# Why can ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer read a cache service?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, map-service

I received a cache folder created from a MXD that I don't possess. Then I was asked to publish that cache as a map service. 
To do that, I created a map service using a MXD (I created) that contains one layer. That layer has no relation with the cache. 
Then I configured the map service to use the cache I was given.

In a !flex application, when I use the map service using esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, it works : I get on the map what the cache contains, not what the MXD contains.

I'm a little confused. ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer is not supposed to read from the cache of the service! Only ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer is supposed to be able to read from the cache. Am I wrong?

Why do I get the cached data on the map instead of the MXD data (which is different from the cache)?

Here is a simple graphic explaining the situation.

[image]

Regards.

Comment: you either need to post some visuals or clarify further.

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: Are the name of both the services same? Did you update the REST cache after deleting the original service? You should debug the requests with firebug, and see what is the url of images.

Comment: There is no original service. All I have is a folder containing the cache that was created by someone else on another platform that I know nothing about.
I was given that folder and asked to publish that cache as a map service on my platform.

Comment: What is the  Name of the folder? Why don't you delete it, if you don't require it?

Comment: I didn't delete that cache folder because I need to create a map service that reads from it.

Comment: What happens if you try creating a new Tiled/Cached map service based on the MXD? Once you set up the cache with Server Manager or ArcCatalog, the cached folders (empty to start) should appear in the server cache directory. Then, if the folder structures match, you should be able to copy in the cache data that was provided to you. If they don't match, then you'll need to get more info about how it was created.

Comment: That's exaclty what I did. And my question is : why when I use the map service with the Flex API object ArcGISDynamicMapService I get on the map what the cache contains.
Normally, I shouldn't be able to read the cache with an ArcGISDynamicMapService. It's with ArcGISTiledMapService that I would be able to read the cache?!